# Can i call a Method from an external JS File in a ServiceWorker?

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, service-worker

Is it possible to call a function from a JavaScript file out of an ServiceWorker?

**Directory**

```
root
   static
      js
         serviceworker.js

   tmpBuild
      js
         pages
            Overview.js
```

**serviceworker.js** has to call a method from **Overview.js**! Is that possible? And How?

Answer (score 4):

You can use **importScripts()** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts

```
importScripts('https://example.com/script.js');
```

Comment: Allready tryed that, but there is always an error occuring, that its a unallowed redirect!

Comment: Is your Overview.js web accessible?

Comment: No if you try to go to it, you will be redirected to start page

Comment: You should probably move this script to a web accessible folder.