# How can i call a javascript function written in my main javascript file from my serviceworker javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a serviceworker.js file which gets registered after page is load. But i can't seem to access a function in my main.js file from this service worker.js file.

I have tried using document.write to write the main.js script into my serviceworker.js file, even tried importing the script with importScripts(),$.getScripts,jQuery.getScript but they all respond with an error of document,$,jQuery undefined respectively. The importScripts() function throws the WorkerGlobalScope error and says "failed to import script".

```
self.addEventListener('sync', event => {
  if(event.tag == 'save-status') {
    event.waitUntil(
      worker.fetch_item_Outbox('syncOrderStatus')
        .then(async data => {await pos.updateOrderStatus(data);
        return worker.clear_item_outbox(data,'syncOrderStatus');
      }))
  }
})
```

//the function i wish to call is the updateOrderStatus() function, inside the pos object of another js file

I want to access the updateOrderStatus() function, inside the pos object of another js file

Comment: Here is solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46932573/1347601

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i call a Method from an external JS File in a ServiceWorker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932176/can-i-call-a-method-from-an-external-js-file-in-a-serviceworker)

Answer (score -1):

ServiceWorkers are necessarily restricted in the functionality that is surfaced. For instance you can not modify the DOM and jQuery us out.

You can use postMessage() in the ServiceWorker to trigger an event and communicate with the main UI thread.